# Is there an implementation of an XElement or XDocument which uses dynamic?

Tags: .net, dynamic, xml-serialization

I'm wondering if there is a built-in or open-source implementation of DynamicXml?

Something like

```
var djson = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(jsonText);
int id = djson.Id;
```

but for xml strings.

So rather than write

```
xitem.Element("SomeElement")
```

I'd like to have

```
dxitem.SomeElement
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656)'s [C# In Depth](http://www.csharpindepth.com/) talks about this idea in Chapter 14 (the chapter on dynamic bahviour in C# 4), and there's downloadable source [here](http://www.csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A quick [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic%20xml%20C#%204) yields several implementations of reading and writing XML using C# 4 dynamic:

- http://tore.vestues.no/2009/01/05/creating-a-dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-40/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/04/dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-and-net-4-0.aspx
- http://michaelmonteleone.net/2010/06/21/suspiciously-pleasant-xml-with-csharp-4/
- http://nomadic-developer.com/2010/04/05/using-dynamic-with-c-to-read-xml/
- http://www.justnbusiness.com/post/2009/07/08/The-Illusion-of-Strongly-Typed-XML-with-C.aspx

and probably many more

Answer (score 0):

Recently I spent some time building dynamic wrapper around `XElement` and `XDocument` for one of my projects, you can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/SergeyTeplyakov/DynamicXml).

Idea exactly the same but I split implementation into two separate classes: `DynamicXmlReader` and `DynamicXmlWriter`, where former could only read elements and attributes and later could add subelements and attributes. And `DynamicXmlReader` throws an exception if it could not find appropriate sub element or attribute but `DynamicXmlWriter` adds them into underlying `XElement`.

For example, here two of my unit tests where I'm using sample from Jon Skeet's book:

```
[TestCase]
public void SkeetBookXmlTest()
{
string books =
@"<books>
  <book name=""Mortal Engines"">
    <author name=""Philip Reeve"" />
  </book>
  <book name=""The Talisman"">
    <author name=""Stephen King"" />
    <author name=""Peter Straub"" />
  </book>
  <book name=""Rose"">
    <author name=""Holly Webb"" />
    <excerpt>Rose was remembering the illustrations from Morally Instructive Tales for the Nursery.</excerpt>
  </book>
</books>";
    dynamic dynamicXml = XElement.Parse(books).AsDynamic();

    Assert.That(dynamicXml.book[0]["name"].Value, Is.EqualTo("Mortal Engines"));

    Assert.That(dynamicXml.book[0].author["name"].Value, Is.EqualTo("Philip Reeve"));

    Assert.That(dynamicXml.book[2]["name"].Value, Is.EqualTo("Rose"));

    Assert.That((string)dynamicXml.book[2].excerpt, Is.EqualTo("Rose was remembering the illustrations from Morally Instructive Tales for the Nursery."));

}
```

Or another unit test that creates exactly the same xml document:

```
[TestCase]
public void SkeetBookXmlTest()
{
    // Jon Skeet in his C# in Depth used following sample
    string books =
@"<books>
  <book name=""Mortal Engines"">
    <author name=""Philip Reeve"" />
  </book>
  <book name=""The Talisman"">
    <author name=""Stephen King"" />
    <author name=""Peter Straub"" />
  </book>
  <book name=""Rose"">
    <author name=""Holly Webb"" />
    <excerpt>Rose was remembering the illustrations from Morally Instructive Tales for the Nursery.</excerpt>
  </book>
</books>";

// Lets create this data dynamically
XElement element = new XElement("books");
dynamic dynamicXml = element.AsDynamicWriter();

dynamicXml.book[0]["name"] = "Mortal Engines";
dynamicXml.book[0].author["name"] = "Philip Reeve";

dynamicXml.book[1]["name"] = "The Tailisman";
dynamicXml.book[1].author[0]["name"] = "Stephen King";
dynamicXml.book[1].author[1]["name"] = "Peter Straub";

dynamicXml.book[2]["name"] = "Rose";
dynamicXml.book[2].author["name"] = "Holly Webb";
dynamicXml.book[2].excerpt = "Rose was remembering the illustrations from Morally Instructive Tales for the Nursery.";

Console.WriteLine(element);

Assert.That(dynamicXml.book[0]["name"].Value, Is.EqualTo("Mortal Engines"));

Assert.That(dynamicXml.book[0].author["name"].Value, Is.EqualTo("Philip Reeve"));

Assert.That(dynamicXml.book[2]["name"].Value, Is.EqualTo("Rose"));

Assert.That((string)dynamicXml.book[2].excerpt, Is.EqualTo("Rose was remembering the illustrations from Morally Instructive Tales for the Nursery."));

}
```